# Overstock qty query SQL server

Tags: sql-server

This question is a little modified based on the recommendation from Eric:

**What I want to achieve:** In order to determine an appropriate obsolescence provision level I would need to calculate an overstock qty per material item and per warehouse (we have several warehouses). The overstock qty will then be the basis for obsolescence calculations.

In order to achieve this I need to compare the current stock level in our warehouses with the consumption of stock in the past 5 years. However first of all I would like to aggregate the stock qty for all of our warehouses (should be a separate column "StockAll" in output table).  Important is that I don´t want one unique entry per item code. E.g. item code ABC is on stock in warehouse1 (5pc) and warehouse2 (5Pc) then the new column "StockAll" should contain 10pc for item code ABC and should pop up twice in the output table namely for warehouse1 and warehouse2.

The overstock (should be a new column "OverstockAll" in output table) is the difference "Stock All" and SH2.BAAS_qty_sold (the qty coming from the union to be found in the code below). Last but not least I need to allocate the Overstock qty being shown in output column "OverstockAll" by using each warehouse share on the correspondent material item number. I.e. based on the example above for item ABC. Stock all shows 10 PC and assume that result of Overstock all is 6PC for ABC. Then I would  like to have separate column "overstock Local" in the output table  which shows for warehouse1 3pc as overstock and the same for warehouse2 (each warehouse has 5pc on stock for material ABC and hence each warehouse should get allocated 50% of the "overstockall, hence 6*0,5)

Is there anybody whith an idea how to achieve this?

```
select  
        bds.[Warehouse code]
        ,bds.[Item code]
        ,bds.[Free text 2]
        ,bds.[Current Stock]
        ,bds.[unit cost]
        ,bds.[unit cost currency] 
        ,SH2.BAAS_qty_sold 
        ,case
            when bds.[Current Stock]-SH2.BAAS_qty_sold >0 
            then  bds.[Current Stock]-SH2.BAAS_qty_sold
            else 0
            end as overstock
```

from [BAAS_PowerBI].[dbo].[BAAS_Daily_Stock]  as bds
Left join

```
        (select 
        sum(SH.Bill_qty) as BAAS_qty_sold 
        , SH.MM_Material 
        from 

        -- Union starts here
        (SELECT 
            Bill_BillingDate
            , MM_Material
            , Bill_qty 
            FROM dbo.BAAS_Bill_done 
            UNION All 
        SELECT 
        Bill_BillingDate
        , MM_Material
        , Bill_qty 
        FROM [BAAS_PowerBI].dbo.[GreatPlains Sales History 2012-102017]) SH
        where 
        sh.Bill_BillingDate > dateadd(year, -5, getdate())
        group by 
        SH.MM_Material) SH2
```

on bds.[Item code]= SH2.[mm_material]

Thank you in advance

Br

c.

Comment: Add a column in your select statement ...                                                                select  
            [BAAS_PowerBI].[dbo].[BAAS_Daily_Stock].[Warehouse code]
         .......................................................................................................
            ,[BAAS_PowerBI].[dbo].[BAAS_Daily_Stock].[unit cost currency] 
            ,SH2.BAAS_qty_sold ,([current stock] -sh2.Baas_qty_sold) as overstock_per_material .......

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? The `CASE` expression calculates a difference if the `current stock` is greater than the `5_yr_consumption`. Otherwise it returns a `0`.

Also, I added a table alias for readability, and changed the `JOIN` from a `LEFT` to an `INNER`, since you won't have any overstock on items you don't have sales records for.

```
SELECT
  bds.[Warehouse code]
 ,bds.[Item code]
 ,bds.[Free text 2]
 ,bds.[Current Stock]
 ,bds.[unit cost]
 ,bds.[unit cost currency]
 ,SH2.BAAS_qty_sold AS 5_yr_consumption
 ,CASE 
    WHEN bds.[Current Stock] > SH2.BAAS_qty_sold 
      THEN bds.[Current Stock] - SH2.BAAS_qty_sold
    ELSE 0
  END AS Overstock
FROM
  BAAS_PowerBI.dbo.BAAS_Daily_Stock AS bds
JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      BAAS_qty_sold = SUM(SH.Bill_qty)
     ,SH.MM_Material
    FROM
    -- Union starts here
      (
        SELECT
          Bill_BillingDate
         ,MM_Material
         ,Bill_qty
        FROM
          dbo.BAAS_Bill_done
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
          Bill_BillingDate
         ,MM_Material
         ,Bill_qty
        FROM
          BAAS_PowerBI.dbo.[GreatPlains Sales History 2012-102017]
      ) AS SH
    WHERE
      SH.Bill_BillingDate > DATEADD(YEAR, -5, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY
      SH.MM_Material
  )                                 AS SH2
    ON
    bds.[Item code] = SH2.mm_material
```

If all the boss cares about is inventory that actually HAS an overstock, just add this:

```
WHERE 
  CASE 
    WHEN bds.[Current Stock] > SH2.BAAS_qty_sold 
      THEN bds.[Current Stock] - SH2.BAAS_qty_sold
    ELSE 0
  END > 0
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer . In addition I would need to aggregate the stock qty for an item code over all warehouses and show this in separate column (stock all). I tried to integrate a sum formula but it failed. Important is I don´t want one unique entry per item code. E.g. item code ABC is on stock in warehouse1 (5pc) and warehouse2 (5Pc) then the new column stock all should contain 10pc for item code ABC and should pop up twice in the output table namely for warehouse1 and warehouse2. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: That raises an entirely separate set of requirements, and probably results in a completely different answer. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to either edit your question as needed or to construct a new question with all of your requirements listed.